# Two consecutive relative pronouns "was": What do they each qualify?

Tags: relative-clause

> Es gibt **nichts**, **was** sie sagen könnte, **was** die Tatsache ändern oder auch nur rechtfertigen würde.

---

For the sake of argument, we will consider:

> Part A = "**nichts**"
>
> Part B = "**was** er sagen könnte"
>
> Part C = "**was** die Tatsache ändern oder auch nur rechtfertigen würde"

---

At first, I was under the impression that both B and C ***separately*** and ***individually*** qualify A:

> There's nothing she could say; ***and*** there's nothing that could change or justify the fact.

But I realised that it would be strange to say "there's nothing she could say", because nothing should hold her back from expressing her own opinion.

---

Now, I wonder if C actually qualifies B, and B and C ***as a whole*** qualify A:

> There's nothing she could  say ***that*** could change or justify the fact.
>
> = She couldn't possibly say anything ***that*** could change or justify the fact.

Here, I think the sentence means "she can say whatever she wants, sure, but she ***could not say a thing that*** could change or justify the fact".

---

It might be similar to how it works in programming languages:

> [ Part A { Part B ( Part C ) } ]

instead of:

> { Part A ( Part B ) } & { Part A ( Part C ) }

---

I wonder if you can rephrase the entire sentence, using only one *was*:

> **Nichts**, **was** er sagen könnte, **würde** die Tatsache ändern oder auch nur rechtfertigen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct with your second guessing:

> C actually qualifies B, and B and C as a whole qualify A:
>
> **There's nothing she could say that could change or justify the fact.**

And yes, if you rephrase your sentence to

> Nichts, was er sagen könnte, würde die Tatsache ändern oder auch nur
>   rechtfertigen.

, its semantics don't change.